# I cant use .push in my array with angular? Cannot read property jsonArr of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am triying yo save data using angular service like this :

```
   @Injectable()
    export class DataServiceProvider {


    url;
  jsonArr = [];


  constructor(public http: Http) {   
    this.url='assets/data/userProfiles.json';
  }

  getProfiles(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.url).
      subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data.json());
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }


    proccessProfiles(){
        this.getProfiles().then(
          data=>{
            data[0].companies.forEach(function(cur){
              this.jsonArr.push({
                name: cur.name,
                profile: "company"
              });
            })

            data[1].centers.forEach(function(cur){
              this.jsonArr.push({
                name: cur.name,
                profile: "center"

              });
            })
          }
        )
      }

    }
```

when i called in my app.component.ts:

I've imported this :

import {DataServiceProvider} from '../providers/data-service/data-service';

and in this function I call:

```
openPopup(){
    console.log('Openpopup ');
    this.modalCtrl.create(ProfilePage).present();   


    this._ds.proccessProfiles();

  }
```

It return error :

Cannot read property jsonArr   of undefined

Do you someone how can i solve that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are not instantiating that service anywhere. If you want a singleton, you need to add it in the `constructor()` as one of the parameters, and it gets injected there and retrieves the instance. You can then use `this` to access it.

`constuctor(_ds: DataServiceProvider)`

Comment: I've declared it where i am using, i will put in context : User has a profiles associated it and i need to create a "global" variable where i put profiles and user in a JSON to manage that and create a logic where user can choose 1 to show in Menu like Hello "Alex" so if user click in "Admin" i will open modal with profiles like "Admin","Comunity Manager" and if user click in "Admin" now menu will Show Hello "Admin" and in modal will be "Alex" and "Comunity Manager".  I hope you can help me , thank you in advance

Comment: oh, my bad. in the function if `forEach`, there is a different `this` object. You'll have to switch those to arrow functions:
data[0].companies.forEach((cur) => {
              this.jsonArr.push({
                name: cur.name,
                profile: "company"
              });
            })

Answer (score 0):

Try by binding `this`

```
proccessProfiles(){
    this.getProfiles().then(
      data=>{
        data[0].companies.forEach(function(cur){
          this.jsonArr.push({
            name: cur.name,
            profile: "company"
          });
        }.bind(this)) // changed here

        data[1].centers.forEach(function(cur){

          this.jsonArr.push({
            name: cur.name,
            profile: "center"

          });
        }.bind(this)) //changed here
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much but it doesnt function, if you want help me , read the top.